# TSQL View, Exclude rows where one column value equals another

Tags: t-sql, view, sql-server-2008-r2

I've created a view for daily totals. I need to exclude rows to get more accurate figures. 
There are two columns (amongst others) in the view named PaymentCode and CustomerID. I need to exclude rows where `PaymentCode = Account and CustomerID = CASHLIG`

Tried using <> which doesn't work as it then takes out everything where PaymentCode = Account
which is not what I need.

Sample data

```
| PAYMENTCODE | CUSTOMERID |
----------------------------
|        CASH |    CASHLIG |
|       CCARD |    CASHLIG |
|     ACCOUNT |  10VICT003 |
|     ACCOUNT |    CASHLIG |
|       CCARD |    CASHLIG |
|     ACCOUNT |    CASHLIG |
```

Any suggestions? I tried searching for an answer to this but wasn't sure how to phrase it.

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post what you've tried so far.  Code is always helpful.

Comment: Please show some sample data and expected output. I have a hard time understanding the problem.

Comment: You'll see that there are a few rows that have sPayMCode = Account and CustomerID = CASHLIG, these are the rows I need to exclude. 

Sample code: http://i.imgur.com/gUF2ZXe.png
Output: http://i.imgur.com/TVy9xH4.png

If you need more info please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED** Try

```sql
CREATE VIEW vw_DailyTotals AS
SELECT ...
  FROM ...
 WHERE PaymentCode <> 'ACCOUNT'
    OR CustomerID  <> 'CASHLIG'
```

Sample output:

```
| PAYMENTCODE | CUSTOMERID |
----------------------------
|        CASH |    CASHLIG |
|       CCARD |    CASHLIG |
|     ACCOUNT |  10VICT003 |
|       CCARD |    CASHLIG |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a40cb/1)** demo.

Comment: Hi Peter, here's an image of the two columns http://i.imgur.com/pW30Ynh.png the two rows where you see sPayMCode = Account and CustomerID = CASHLIG must be excluded, I tried your example above and it seems to be doing what I need, I'll just check my figures. Thanks for your answer. I'll update you on whether it works or not.

Comment: @Mordecai OK. Here is **[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a40cb/1)** with your sample data. Please take a look. Does it give you the result you want?

Comment: Ok, it seems to be working in the current view, the rows are not showing anymore. I'll just have to check my final view where the daily totals are broken down by company.

Comment: Thanks peter, it did work and is doing exactly what I need but there's some figures that aren't matching another report. The daily totals works off of 3 views. I'd go into detail but it's a long story. This will be very useful in future scenarios, thanks. I'm going to figure out how I can automate and e-mail a crystal report. Once again, thanks.